# not able ot show date in x axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime, highcharts

i want to show date in x asis but not able to show. showing values like this 00.00.00.100 in the graph.unable to convert 1577844000000 to proper date,month,year in javascript to show in the x axis using dateTimeLabelFormats in highcharts.how to use ticks and how to show it in graphs.
ticks values are printing in the console like this.
sample tick data

```
    1577844000000
    1577843100000
    1577842200000
    1577841300000
    15778404000
```

sample data from the response

```
DeviceTimeStamp: "2020-01-10T00:30:00"
```

[image: highcharts graph screenshot]

code

```
  getalldata();

                    function getalldata() {
                        var xhttp_roomlogs = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp_roomlogs.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp_roomlogs.responseText);

                                 var Ch1Temp = [];
                                 var Ch2Temp = [];

                        $(response).each(function (i, item) {
                            var date = UtcToIst(item.DeviceTimeStamp);
                            var ticks = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
                            Ch1Temp.push([ticks, item.Ch1Temp])
                            Ch2Temp.push([ticks, item.Ch2Temp])//
                        });

                        $('#container').empty();
                                var labels = response.map(function (e) {
                                    var roomtempdata = e.Ch1Temp;
                                    return parseFloat(roomtempdata);
                                })
                                var ch2temp = response.map(function (e) {
                                    var roomtempdata = e.Ch2Temp;
                                    return parseFloat(roomtempdata);
                                })

                                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                                    credits: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Chamber 1 & 2 Temp'
                                    },

                                    subtitle: {
                                        text: 'in Degree Celcius'
                                    },
                                    xAxis: {
                                        type: 'datetime',
                                        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                                        month: '%e. %b',
                                        year: '%b'
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Date'
                                }
                                    },
                                    yAxis: {
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Temperature'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    legend: {
                                        layout: 'vertical',
                                        align: 'right',
                                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                                    },

                                    //y co-ordinates
                                    series: [{
                                        name: 'Chamber 1 Temp',
                                        data: labels
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'Chamber 2 Temp',
                                        data: ch2temp
                                    }


                                    ],
                                    responsive: {
                                        rules: [{
                                            condition: {
                                                maxWidth: 500
                                            },
                                            chartOptions: {
                                                legend: {
                                                    layout: 'horizontal',
                                                    align: 'center',
                                                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }

                                });

                                //highcharts end
                            }
                        };

                        xhttp_roomlogs.open("GET", "/api/data", true);

                     xhttp_roomlogs.send();
                    }

                    function UtcToIst(data) {
                        var dt = new Date(data);
                        return dt;
                    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or CodePen? The image is barely visible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kwtZr/1/
but working api i have not kept.

Comment: Hi @krishna mohan, You need to convert date values to timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the json date using:

```js
var jsonDate = "\/Date(1577844000000)\/".substr(6);
var dateObject = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate ));
var stringDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();
console.log("Dat Object:" + dateObject);
console.log("String Date:" + stringDate);
```

sample hightchart code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/4/2020', '1/5/2020']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            labelFormatter: function () {
                if(this.data.length > 0) {
           return this.data[0].category;
                } else {
                    return this.name;
                }
      }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{x:0,y:1}],
            name: '1/1/2020'
        },{
            data: [{x:1,y:1}],
            name: '1/2/2020'
        },{
            data: [{x:2,y:1}],
            name: '1/3/2020'
        },{
            data: [{x:3,y:1}],
            name: '1/4/2020'
        },{
            data: [{x:4,y:1}],
            name: '1/5/2020'
        }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: value now getting correct in console but how to put in x axis any idea ?

Comment: updated the question is this sample solve your issue?

Comment: because i believe that your hightcharts code is missing the categories part

Comment: thanks for the update chart is working but my main concern is when data is more than. its showing date in vertical manner . i wanted to show ony few dates , that y i was trying some tick or datetimelabel format. plz try the same code with some 20 values u will find the issue

Comment: this is the responsive behaviour of the hightcharts when the charts cannot show the full list it tries in many ways to show, like vertical text and hiding small values

Comment: i dont want to show all x axis values in the x axis . i want to show few of them but in hover and graph it should come all points. like this https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/spline